NonLinearModelFit giving unidentifiable error message
So I am relatively new at fitting data on Mathematica, but I am currently trying to do a Nonlinear model fitting to the data below, but it keeps giving me the error "NonlinearModelFit::nrlnum: Thefunction value is not a list of real numbers with dimensions (4948) at (x0,y0,d)=(1.,1.,1.)." error. I tried adding constraints to the function, but it still gives me an error, so what can I do to fix this? Please let me know and thank you so much!
Data:
    {{"Temp", "R"}, {40.0362, 0.0000588764}, {39.9931, 
  0.0000588351}, {39.9494, 0.0000588433}, {39.9046, 
  0.0000588351}, {39.8618, 0.0000588598}, {39.8186, 
  0.0000587522}, {39.7744, 0.0000587522}, {39.7292, 
  0.0000587689}, {39.6865, 0.0000586942}, {39.6416, 
  0.0000587358}, {39.5979, 0.0000587024}, {39.5547, 
  0.0000587024}, {39.5096, 0.0000586198}, {39.4657, 
  0.0000586778}, {39.4219, 0.000058686}, {39.3776, 
  0.0000586116}, {39.3323, 0.000058686}, {39.2895, 
  0.0000586447}, {39.2442, 0.0000586198}, {39.1999, 
  0.0000584791}, {39.1547, 0.0000585784}, {39.1103, 
  0.0000585453}, {37.354, 
  0.0000580402}, {23.1903, 
  0.0000549607}, {23.0885, 0.0000549607}, {22.9847, 
  0.0000551593}, {21.0465, 
  0.0000547289}, {20.9349, 0.0000548449}, {20.8195, 
  0.0000548118}, {20.7053, 0.0000547702}, {20.59, 
  0.0000546876}, {20.4707, 0.0000547951}, {20.3502, 
  0.0000547124}, {20.2321, 0.0000546131}, {20.1124, 
  0.0000546876}, {19.9936, 0.0000546793}, {19.8747, 
  0.0000546378}, {19.7546, 0.0000546296}, {19.6341, 
  0.000054522}, {19.5082, 0.0000545633}, {19.3858, 
  0.0000545964}, {19.2587, 0.0000546047}, {19.1304, 
  0.0000545964}, {19.0073, 0.000054464}, {18.8789, 
  0.0000545053}, {18.7511, 0.0000545551}, {18.6181, 
  0.0000545882}, {9.66403, 
  0.0000544476}, {9.53691, 0.0000543978}, {9.41754, 
  0.0000545384}, {9.30397, 0.0000546047}, {9.18099, 
  0.0000545551}, {9.05984, 0.0000546047}, {8.94078, 
  0.0000545633}, {8.82504, 0.0000546627}, {8.70886, 
  0.0000546958}, {8.59863, 0.0000544476}, {8.49309, 
  0.0000546627}, {8.38439, 0.0000548118}, {8.27785, 
  0.0000546047}, {8.1802, 0.0000546709}, {8.08738, 
  0.0000546876}, {7.99145, 0.0000546131}, {7.89202, 
  0.0000547289}, {7.78878, 0.0000546793}, {7.68565, 
  0.0000547207}, {7.58928, 0.0000547371}, {7.50183, 
  0.0000547787}, {7.40628, 0.00005482}, {7.31759, 
  0.0000547456}, {3.82444, 
  0.0000554491}, {3.78569, 0.0000553996}, {3.75951, 
  0.0000554658}, {3.72983, 0.0000553996}, {3.67449, 
  0.0000553333}, {3.62912, 0.0000554491}, {3.59314, 
  0.0000553829}, {3.54487, 0.0000554658}, {3.51058, 
  0.0000553084}, {3.47086, 0.0000554409}, {3.43896, 
  0.0000554904}, {3.41296, 0.0000554078}, {3.37425, 
  0.0000554491}, {3.31943, 0.0000554989}, {3.2751, 
  0.000055532}, {3.25791, 0.0000554409}, {3.23074, 
  0.0000555153}, {3.20137, 0.000055532}, {3.15882, 
  0.0000554989}, {3.12217, 0.0000554491}, {3.08307, 
  0.0000555153}, {3.04117, 0.0000555153}, {3.00086, 
  0.000055474}, {2.97353, 0.0000555484}, {2.8924, 
  0.0000555153}, {2.88487, 0.0000555153}, {2.84489, 
  0.000055474}, {2.76539, 0.0000555153}, {2.68384, 
  0.0000555071}, {2.59639, 0.0000556644}, {2.50823, 
  0.0000555402}, {2.43769, 0.0000556313}, {2.37621, 
  0.0000555567}, {2.29244, 0.0000555816}, {2.22631, 
  0.0000555567}, {2.15238, 0.0000557307}, {2.08816, 
  0.0000557058}, {2.0339, 0.0000556809}, {1.98383, 
  0.0000556396}, {1.94399, 0.0000556064}, {1.90875, 
  0.0000556313}, {1.88658, 0.000055656}, {1.87242, 
  0.000055656}, {1.86178, 0.0000557058}, {1.85283, 
  0.0000557884}, {1.84449, 0.0000557471}, {1.83687, 
  0.000055714}, {1.82925, 0.0000557222}, {1.82201, 
  0.0000556644}, {1.81512, 0.0000556727}, {1.80857, 
  0.0000556229}, {1.80229, 0.000055656}, {1.79616, 
  0.0000557307}, {1.79043, 0.0000558382}, {1.78488, 
  0.0000557307}, {1.77969, 0.0000556976}, {1.77467, 
  0.0000556891}, {1.77006, 0.0000557307}, {1.76554, 
  0.000055656}, {1.76127, 0.0000557802}, {1.75726, 
  0.0000557389}, {1.75325, 0.0000557307}, {1.74951, 
  0.0000557553}, {1.74627, 0.0000557471}, {1.74372, 
  0.0000555982}, {1.74156, 0.0000557222}, {1.73961, 
  0.0000556313}, {1.73777, 0.0000557307}, {1.73598, 
  0.0000556147}, {1.64909, 
  0.0000556891}, {1.64908, 0.0000557471}, {1.64911, 
  0.0000556891}, {1.6491, 0.0000557553}, {1.6491, 
  0.0000557884}, {1.64909, 0.0000557969}, {1.64909, 
  0.0000557471}, {1.64909, 0.000055772}, {1.64908, 
  0.0000556891}, {1.64907, 0.000055656}, {1.64905, 
  0.0000557389}, {1.64905, 0.0000557307}, {1.64905, 
  0.000055772}, {1.64447, 0.0000557307}, {1.64448, 
  0.0000557471}, {1.64447, 0.0000557222}, {1.64445, 
  0.0000556891}, {1.64445, 0.0000556478}, {1.64444, 
  0.0000557471}, {1.63996, 0.0000557969}, {1.63996, 
  0.0000556891}, {1.63878, 
  0.000055656}, {1.63878, 0.0000556644}, {1.63877, 
  0.0000556644}, {1.63876, 0.0000557638}}

Here is the attempted code for my fitting function:
NonlinearModelFit[data, {y0*Exp[(x0/x)^(1/(1 + d))]}, {x0, y0, d}, x]


Can you try restarting Mathematica and just do data={40.0362, 0.0000588764},...}; NonlinearModelFit[data,{y0*Exp[(x0/x)^(1/(1+d))]},{x0,y0,d},x] and run that code and tell us what it displays? I'm not getting anything like dimension 4948 which makes me think you have not restarted Mathematica and maybe assignments you have made are hiding in cache and you don't know that.

Adding a constraint to the search for parameters yields an answer, but different from Tapiocaweasel's: nlm = NonlinearModelFit[Rest@data, {y0*Exp[(x0/x)^(1/(1 + d))], x0 > 0}, {x0, y0, d}, x]

If I use Michael's code nlm =Normal[ NonlinearModelFit[Rest@data, {y0*Exp[(x0/x)^(1/(1+d))],x0>0},{x0,y0,d},x]];Show[ListPlot[Rest@data,PlotRange->All],Plot[Evaluate[nlm],{x,.163876,40.0362}]]  that looks like a really really bad fit ;} Have I made a terrible mistake? I am not sure from that ListPlot whether the model that is trying to be fit can actually be a good fit for any possible parameters or not.

Thank you so much for your helps! I am simply trying to see what was wrong. As for the fit, I assumed it was also bad to begin with. Now it seems to be working.

@Bill How can I show the output of the best parameters from the fit?

@Dave2627 I'm not sure exactly what way you want to use the parameters. That might change the answer. Try Normal[NonlinearModelFit[...]] and see if the format of that can give you what you need.

@Bill Thank you! I mainly want to use the parameters to get a baseline of the values to see if I can get a decent/better fit.

First, your data need to be just the {x1,...,xn,f[x1,...,xn]} format, so  use Rest to drop the first element with the labels.
then, you need to prevent your function from producing non-real results during the internals of the evaluation. I did this by doing Abs@x0 to keep the argument of Exp real.
Then I actually was puzzled because it was working? but not? The last thing to get the normal result was to remove the {} around your model
ClearAll[x0, y0, d, data]
(*data= your list*)
fit = NonlinearModelFit[data // Rest, 
  y0*Exp[(Abs[x0]/x)^(1/(1 + d))], {x0, y0, d}, x]

gives
fit["BestFitParameters"](*{x0 -> -0.355462, y0 -> 0.0000557605, d -> -0.976227}*)


If I use those results: x0=-0.355462; y0=0.0000557605;d=-0.976227; Show[ListPlot[ data,PlotRange->All],Plot[y0*Exp[(x0/x)^(1/(1 + d))],{x,.163876,40.0362}]] that looks like a really really bad fit ;} Have I made a terrible mistake?

I have no idea @Bill, I just fixed it until it gave some output, I didn't check the output. I was simply attempting to get the fit to actually produce some output, not necessarily good output!

Understood. I'm not sure whether his model can give good output.

Thank you @Tapiocaweasel it seems to be working with your help! Now I can try different functions to fit.
